# JobIntentService not working in android Q

Tags: android, service, background-service, jobintentservice

**onHandleWork** is not triggering. The Service is working fine below android 10.

```
class IncidentImageUploadService : JobIntentService() {

    private var eventModel: String? = null
    private var incidentId: Int? = null
    private var sS3Client: AmazonS3Client? = null
    private var sMobileClient: AWSCredentialsProvider? = null
    private var sTransferUtility: TransferUtility? = null


    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {

        eventModel = intent.getStringExtra(BeontConstant.UPLOAD_ADD_INCIDENT_IMAGE)
        incidentId = intent.getIntExtra(BeontConstant.INCIDENT_ID, -1)
        if (eventModel != null) {
            if (!eventModel!!.isNullOrEmpty()) {
               println("message"+eventModel)

            }
        }

    }

    override fun onStopCurrentWork(): Boolean {
        return true
    }
 companion object {
        val JOB_ID = 23

        fun enqueueWork(context: Context, work: Intent) {
            enqueueWork(context, IncidentImageUploadService::class.java, JOB_ID, work)
        }
}

}
```

This is how i am starting the JobIntentService:

```
  val intentUpload =  Intent(activity!!, IncidentImageUploadService::class.java)
                            intentUpload.putExtra(BeontConstant.UPLOAD_ADD_INCIDENT_IMAGE, fileName)
                            intentUpload.putExtra(BeontConstant.INCIDENT_ID, model.id)
                            IncidentImageUploadService.enqueueWork(activity!!, intentUpload)
```

This is how I have defined service in the manifest under application:

```
 <service
            android:name=".services.IncidentImageUploadService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check for system Logcat messages. Also, consider switching to `WorkManager`.

Comment: Not getting anything in the Logcat.